# Need to display the widgets inside my QListWidget with an offset, basically shifted a bit to the right

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a panel.ui file done using QTDesigner. It's a QFrame class, rectangular shape with few labels on it. And I have a QListWidget class where I insert 3 instances of the panel.ui.
I create a `QListWidgetItem` and then use `List->SetItemWidget(..)` to populate my list.
The Result is a list filled with three panels. I was also able to move the panels inside the list using dragDropMode internalMove.

I also tested the ability to shift the panels a bit to the right when I click on them and that worked:

```
in procedure List::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)    
Panel *child = static_cast<Panel*>(childAt(event->pos()))  
...   
int y= child->pos().y();   
int x = child->pos().x();   
child->move (x +10, y);   `
```

Problem: When I run the app and display the list, I want all the panels to be displayed with that 10 offset to the right. So in the List constructor and inside the loop after `this->setItemWidget(myPanelItem, myPanel);` I try using `myPanel->move()` like above but it doesn't seem to work.

I run the app, the panels are displayed without my offset ( not sure why?) but when I click on one, it shifts.

Answer (score 0):

`move()` won't work reliably since the widgets are in a layout. (Well, not a layout as in a `QLayout`, but the effect is comparable: When any metric in your application changes, e.g. you resize or scroll the list, the widgets are repositioned by the list widget.)

What you can do is wrap your actual widget in a container widget with a layout margin:

```cpp
QWidget* wrapIntoContainerForOffset(QWidget* widget, int offset /*in pixels*/) {
    QWidget* container = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QLayout(container);
    layout->setContentsMargins(/*left=*/ offset, /*others=*/ 0, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(widget);
    return container;
}
```

Then you add these containers to the listwidget instead.

Comment: @user1991611: Great to hear. Would you please mark the answer as accepted, so that others can quickly identify the answer that helped you most?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried StyleSheets. The QListWidget supports Box model( http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model ). So You may want to try playing around with margins in the stylesheets.

Style sheet reference: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: Thx. I'm new to Qt I read about it but didn't figure out how I could take advantage of stylesheets.